# DIVs deleted when using the "Source" tab of the editor

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, rte

I am trying to get the TYPO3 RTE to accept my div containers.
I read the doc, read other Topics here and it just ALWAYS 
converts the DIVs back into p Tags.

Here is my TS Config that I got from searching.

```
    RTE.default.proc {

    ## TRANSFORMATION METHOD
    ## We assume that CSS Styled Content is used.
  overruleMode = ts_css

    ## DO NOT CONVERT BR TAGS INTO LINEBREAKS
    ## br tags in the content are assumed to be intentional.
  dontConvBRtoParagraph = 1

    ## PRESERVE DIV SECTIONS - DO NOT REMAP TO P
  preserveDIVSections = 1

    ## TAGS ALLOWED OUTSIDE P & DIV
  allowTagsOutside = hr, address

    ## TAGS ALLOWED
  allowTags >
  allowTags (
    a, br, div, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, img, li, link, meta, ol, p, 
    span, table, thead, tbody, tfoot, td, th, tr, hr, ul, title, abbr, acronym, address, b, bdo, big, blockquote, caption, center, cite, code, col, colgroup, del, dfn, i, ins, kbd, label, em, font, tt, u, strike, strong, style, sub, sup, var, pre, q, samp, sdfield, small
    )

    ## TAGS DENIED
    ## Make sure we can set rules on any tag listed in allowTags.
  denyTags >

    ## ALLOWED P & DIV ATTRIBUTES
    ## Attributes class and align are always preserved
    ## Align attribute will be unset on entry (see below)
    ## This is a list of additional attributes to keep
  keepPDIVattribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang

    ## REMAP BOLD AND ITALIC TO STRONG AND EMPHASIS AND VICE VERSA
  transformBoldAndItalicTags = 1

    ## ALLOW TO WRITE ABOUT HTML
  dontUndoHSC_db = 1
  dontHSC_rte = 1

    ## CONTENT TO DATABASE
  entryHTMLparser_db = 1
  entryHTMLparser_db {

      ## TAGS ALLOWED
      ## Always use the same list of allowed tags.
    allowTags < RTE.default.proc.allowTags

      ## TAGS DENIED
      ## Make sure we can set rules on any tag listed in allowTags.
    denyTags >

      ## AVOID CONTENT BEING HSC'ed TWICE
    htmlSpecialChars = 0

    tags {

        ## REMOVE IMG TAGS
        ## By Mike: will be enabled later on!
      img.allowedAttribs = 0
      img.rmTagIfNoAttrib = 1

        ## CLEAN ATTRIBUTES ON THE FOLLOWING TAGS
      span.fixAttrib.style.unset = 1
      p {
        allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
        fixAttrib.align.unset = 1
      }
      div < .p
      span.allowedAttribs = class
      hr.allowedAttribs = class
      b.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      bdo.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      big.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      blockquote.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      cite.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      code.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      del.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      dfn.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      em.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      i.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      ins.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      kbd.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      label.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      q.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      samp.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      small.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      strike.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      strong.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      sub.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      sup.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      tt.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      u.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
      var.allowedAttribs = id, title, dir, lang, xml:lang, class
    }

      ## REMOVE OPEN OFFICE META DATA TAGS, WORD 2003 TAGS, LINK, META, STYLE AND TITLE TAGS, AND DEPRECATED HTML TAGS
      ## We use this rule instead of the denyTags rule so that we can protect custom tags without protecting these unwanted tags.
    removeTags = center, font, link, o:p, sdfield, meta, style, title, strike, u

      ## PROTECT CUSTOM TAGS
    keepNonMatchedTags = protect
  }

  HTMLparser_db {
      ## STRIP ALL ATTRIBUTES FROM THESE TAGS
      ## If this list of tags is not set, it will default to: b,i,u,br,center,hr,sub,sup,strong,em,li,ul,ol,blockquote,strike.
      ## However, we want to keep xml:lang attribute on most tags and tags from the default list where cleaned on entry.
    noAttrib = br

      ## XHTML COMPLIANCE
      ## Note that applying xhtml_cleaning on exit would break non-standard attributes of typolink tags
    xhtml_cleaning = 1
  }

  exitHTMLparser_db = 1
  exitHTMLparser_db {
      ## KEEP ALL TAGS
      ## Unwanted tags were removed on entry.
      ## Without this rule, the parser will remove all tags! Presumably, this rule will be more efficient than repeating the allowTags rule
    keepNonMatchedTags = 1

      ## AVOID CONTENT BEING HSC'ed TWICE
    htmlSpecialChars = 0
  }
}

  ## Use same RTE processing rules in FE
RTE.default.FE.proc < RTE.default.proc

  ## RTE processing rules for bodytext column of tt_content table
  ## Erase settings from other extensions
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext >

  ## Make sure we use ts_css transformation
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.types.text.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
RTE.config.tt_content.bodytext.types.textpic.proc.overruleMode = ts_css
```

I did verify on "Web --> Info" that these settings are indeed taking effect on the Subpage that I am trying to do this on, but still TYPO3 is deleting all my DIVs, when I am using the "Source" tab of the editor on entering my HTML Code.

Note: I am not even at the Stage where the Database would parse anything. As soon as I switch back to the WYSIWYG view of the RTE from the Source Tab, it has completely destroyed the code.

Comment: Okay I am now further than I was before but its still not working. I found out that 99% of the Documentation and Reads I found were referencing the old rte. The new Typo3 used rte_ckeditor!

I have found out that you can customize the behaviour and workings of THIS editor via YAML and although I did now specify a customConfig, it still doesn't work. I will post another update later.